# Doctrine 2 multiple primary keys

Tags: php, mysql, orm, doctrine-orm

For some reason doctrine is trying to insert an index called primary instead of actually adding a primary key on my MYSQL database, this is what Doctrine generates:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX primary ON my_table (columnOne, columnTwo);
```

This is what my SQL editor generates and this is the only method that works:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD PRIMARY KEY  (columnOne,columnTwo);
```

This is my class:

```
....
class MyTable
{
    /**
     * @var integer $columnOne
     *
     * @Column(name="columnOne", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @Id
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
     */
    private $columnOne;

    /**
     * @var integer $columnTwo
     *
     * @Column(name="columnTwo", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @Id
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
     */
    private $columnTwo;
}
```

Comment: How did you solve the problem in the end?

Answer (score 1):

Adding info about Multi-column Unique constraints here because this is what came up when I googled for it.

If you want something like this SQL:

```
CONSTRAINT uc_PersonID UNIQUE (P_Id,LastName)
```

use this annotation in Doctrine2

```
@Table(name="ecommerce_products",uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(name="search_idx", columns={"name", "email"})})
```

see: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/annotations-reference.html#uniqueconstraint